# c# XElement.Parse() retrieve WOEID from yahoo API

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I will strat with what I have done already. So I have following XMLfile:

```
<places yahoo:start="0" yahoo:count="23" yahoo:total="23">
    <place yahoo:uri="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/523920" xml:lang="en-us">
        <woeid>523920</woeid>
        <placeTypeName code="7">Town</placeTypeName>
        <name>Warsaw</name>
        <country type="Country" code="PL" woeid="23424923">Poland</country>
        ...
    </place>
    ...
</places>
```

I skip parts, which are not neccesary (I believe so atleast). Anyway There is <places> which contains variable number of <place> in this particular case it's 23. I do following code:

```
List<XElement> list = XElement.Parse(e.Result).Elements().ToList();
```

As a result I have list of 23 XElements (place), but from some reason I can't get value which is inside <woeid> Bellow code doesn't work :-(

```
foreach (XElement element in list) {
    String woeid = element.Element("woeid").Value;
    // ... sth else to do with each woeid
}
```

Can you help me get those values?

[UPDATE]

I think I have found what you have been asking for @L.B by getting page source from context menu, here is it. Can you help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<places xmlns="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:start="0" yahoo:count="23" yahoo:total="23">
```

[SOLVED]

Thanks for a hint about namespaces. Using Trials and Errors method I have done it. Answer is that, you have to add namespace in bracket before element name as bellow.

```
String woeid = element.Element("{http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng}woeid").Value;
```

And now it just simply works. Thanks once again.

Comment: `I skip parts, which are not neccesary` You skipped the XmlNamespace declarations where your problem lies.

Comment: I skip only dotted parts. It's all that firefox shows me. Message in browser state that there are no-defined styles and document tree is printed. I just copy it here. Where I can get those namespaces?